# When should I plant parsnips in Boston?

Tags: vegetables, root-vegetables, planting-times

I live in Boston, Massachusetts, USA, and would like to know when to plant my parsnip. I use this site and wanted your answer and opinion on the site's answer. https://www.growmigo.com/

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you please summarize what you learned at growmigo? That way we can compare it right here. Links can go down at any time and people won't know what you were referring to. Also, I had a look at that site and don't fully trust it, especially since paid membership is required to unlock the full features. @stormy's brilliant, and is going to sign up for it, so she can tell you what she thinks, but we do need our questions to have as much detail as possible. We have a great [help]. Start with [ask], and if you have any questions about what we do, leave a comment here!

Comment: I'm not assuming or intending to insult you at all, but if you're affiliated with that site in any way, please let us know. Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting the card out.  I'll let you know.  This is just like another resource and I've spent the bucks on books so I should spend a bit on internet resources.

Comment: @koolgro3456  Well, I thought it would be a whole $8 but, no, I had to pay for 12 months!  But good news, their information seems to be solid.  Lacking in depth but they will probably be upgrading as their site matures.  The math is on THEIR end along with their continuing sources such as Cooperative Extension Services.  What I looked up was correct.  I gave them lots of comments for improvement.  Companion planting is NOT necessary and they shall be explaining their lists of good and bad companion planting.  They will also be talking about rotation, water, insects, fungus and soil preparation

Comment: I am going to play with this site for a month and then quit...maybe.  Good resource but I always consult at least two resources when in doubt...if not three.  I am glad they are using Cooperative Extension Services!  Not bad info but they need to give lots more in detail.  I think they are new...and will get better.

Comment: Wow! thanks for your feedback, I appreciate it. This is my first day every to use stackexchange and did not expect people to even answer....Their information was consistent to what I read. Thank you soooo much. By the way, I chose the monthly option and not the annual option...Ap

Answer (score 1):

I plant mine in the spring. Takes a bit longer than other seeds sown into the garden soil to see germination but I am just now getting great parsnips and rutabagas...have you tried rutabagas?  Wonderful mashed with potatoes and made into fries.

I live in zone 1b.  Our winters are tough so anything that needs to be allowed to overwinter has to be started earlier, such as cover crops for barren beds.  Garlic just didn't work here but I shall try this fall for next year because we now have a proper heated and skinned greenhouse.

I haven't looked at your site as yet, I am assuming they want you to plant in the fall?  Need to know your zone and circumstances.  I grew parsnips and rutabagas in zone 3 beneath 11 feet of snow...and they were fine in the spring!  Amazing.  They did fine where the potatoes did not.

I'll check out the site you sent and let you know if I've any more information.

Comment: Interesting.  I have serious doubts that anything in the plant and gardening world could every be predicted with an algorithm, I'll have to sign up to test it.  Experience is far better in my opinion.  Humans do better than computers in the natural world for now.  I am dying to see the inputs for this formula.  Meanwhile, let this brain know more about your plans.  Are you using pots on a balcony?  Critical to know as plants do not do well in pots over winter.  Their roots, the most vulnerable part of any plant are exposed to the cold in a pot.  You HAVE to use potting soil, not garden soil...

Comment: Hi stormy! Please let us know what you think of that site. I don't fully trust it, but you're the absolute expert, and I don't want to make bad assumptions, especially if it could end up hurting koolgro3456's feelings. Thanks!

Comment: I am an expert and being an expert we know we don't know huge amounts of stuff!  Just combining the world of gardening and landscaping with using formulas instead good old hands on experience bothers me greatly.  This is contraindicated for newbies!  Similar to our kids learning math by using a calculator without learning how to do math longhand and in one's head.  There is a major disconnection between human and plant and soil and other animals, insects.  Beautiful landscapes and productive gardens are a by product of a close, physical relationship.  We need being a part of the environment.